# Partially check QListWidget item by mouse click (tristate)

Tags: qt, checkbox, pyqt, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

Qt 4.8. I need some items in my list to have 3 states. So i add the following code:

```
item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem("Hello there")
item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable |
    QtCore.Qt.ItemIsTristate)
item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.PartiallyChecked)
```

An item is successfully set to *partially checked* state on its creation, but further mouse clicks switch it between *checked*/*unchecked* states.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Cause we cannot make `QListWidget` iterate through 3 states automatically in Qt 4.8 (`ItemIsUserTristate` flag was added in Qt 5.5), we'll do it manually:

```
CHECKSTATE_ROLE = 32

def lstFiles_itemChanged(self, item):  # slot
    if item.flags() & QtCore.Qt.ItemIsTristate:
        if item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked and \
                        item.data(CHECKSTATE_ROLE) == QtCore.Qt.Unchecked:
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.PartiallyChecked)
        item.setData(CHECKSTATE_ROLE, item.checkState())

item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem("Buenas noches")
if this_item_needs_tristate:
    item.setFlags(item.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsTristate)
    state = QtCore.Qt.PartiallyChecked
else:
    state = QtCore.Qt.Checked
item.setCheckState(state)
item.setData(CHECKSTATE_ROLE, item.checkState())
```

An item remembers its previous check state in a user data element so we can change states appropriately on `itemChanged`.

Answer (score 2):

`QtCore.Qt.ItemIsTristate` is deprecated, it was replaced by `ItemIsAutoTristate` which handles automatically the partial check status for items with child items.

Since Qt 5.5, you can use `QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserTristate` to have the behavior you want.

Comment: Ok, so `ItemIsTristate` works in `QTreeWidget`. From docs: `Items in hierarchical models may be partially checked if some, but not all, of their children are checked.` In that case it has nothing to do with `QListWidget`. And it's obvious why the flag was renamed into `ItemIsAutoTristate`.